# Tensorflow eval hangs

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow and currently writing an object detection code in tensorflow:

So here is what I'm Doing

1) Read a .csv file that has Image name , label/class, bounding box details. (read_from_csv).

2)Convert the label from csv to onehot encoding.(to_onehot) In this function label.eval(session=sess) causes the system to hang.

I cant understand the problem. The code I wrote is given below. Please help

```
global data_classes
data_classes = ["class1", "class2", "class3"]

#Model-Parameters
batch_size = 32
image_width = 640
image_height = 480
num_channels = 3
num_iters = 200000
validation_ratio = 0.1
num_classes = 7
learning_rate = 0.001
lr_deacay = 0.9


def num_img(csv_name):
    with open(csv_name) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return int(i + 1)


def read_from_csv(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
    _, csv_row = reader.read(filename_queue)
    #train, test = dataset_split(csv_row)
    record_defaults = [[' '],[' '],[' '],[' '],[' '],[' '], [' '], [' '], [' '], [' ']]
    col_Image, col_label, col_xmin, col_ymin, col_xmax, col_ymax, misc1, misc2, misc3, misc4 = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=record_defaults)
    wd=getcwd()
    /* Some Processing for Images */
    # stacked values should be of same datatype
    label = tf.stack([col_label])
    onehot = to_onehot(label)
    print('image',image.get_shape())
    print('label', label.get_shape())
    return image, label


def input_pipeline(batch_size, num_epochs):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([args.dataset], num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True) 
    image, label = read_from_csv(filename_queue)
    min_after_dequeue = 100
    capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
    image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity, min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
    print('image',label_batch.get_shape())
    return image_batch, onehot 

def to_onehot(label,nclasses = num_classes):
    assert tf.get_default_session() is sess
    global data_classes
    print('to_onehot', label)
    **l = label.eval(session=sess) /* This eval is giving error */**
    print(l)
    indices = data_classes.index(l[0]) 
    print(indices)
    outlabels = tf.zeros([label.get_shape().as_list()[0],nclasses])
    /* Some Processing */
    return outlabels



with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    with sess.as_default():
        init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                   tf.local_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(init_op)
        global file_length
    file_length = num_img(args.dataset) - 1
        print(file_length)
        tf.report_uninitialized_variables(name='uninitialized_variable')
        images, labels = input_pipeline(batch_size, 1)


    # start populating filename queue
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

        try:
            while not coord.should_stop():
                image_batch, label_batch = sess.run([images, labels])

        print(label_batch)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('Done training, epoch reached')
        finally:
            coord.request_stop()

    coord.join(threads)


    print("Network Architecture")
/*Some Processing */
```

Comment: What error message did you get? Can you provide the output of `label.shape`?

Comment: @frankyjuang:  this is the output ('to_onehot', <tf.Tensor 'stack:0' shape=(1,) dtype=string>)

Comment: I tried print(tf.shape(label)) and I get output as

Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32, device=/device:CPU:0)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start training queue by calling tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)

Comment: Answers should not rely on links for their content. Links can go dead, or the information they point to can be changed to no longer answer the question. Please put the information you have linked to directly in your answer. Only use links as citations and/or resources for further reading.

Comment: Roger that. Not even sure if I inserted the link correctly. Edited